# How do you uncheck an upvote without selecting a down vote?

Tags: support, down-votes, up-votes

How would you set an up vote to no vote without down voting the answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Downvote inflexibility problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68381/downvote-inflexibility-problem)

Comment: Don't forget there is a short window in which you can undo your vote. After that time it's locked in.

Comment: The big difference in questions is that the "Downvote inflexibility problem" discusses whether these things should be allowed, and mine is just a dumb question in how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the Upvote button again.

Comment: Ah.  That makes sense ...  In any case, there's a 60 minute delay on voting too.

Comment: A couple of times I've accidentally upvoted a comment and discovered that I was not able to undo this by clicking again.  Not a big deal for me, but just something that I noticed.

Comment: It's not a big deal until you upvote someone answering with a totally wrong answer (like what color is Milk and they answer "I didn't wear any pants because it's laundry day").